# I have difficulties in composing an image using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Please find the following image. I have typed kubectl apply -k directory but there is error regarding root path.

I hope someone can help. Is it only able to be deployed in Azure environment?

[image]

If I typed kubectl -f xxx.yaml file. The yaml is found but still error. Sorry I unable to reproduce the problem exists in kubelet once i started the minikube.

Comment: re *I have typed kubectl apply -k directory*  --- you have typed `kubectl apply -k SOMEFILE.yaml`.   A yaml file is not a directory; `-k` needs a directory, as the error states.   If you're applying a single file, use `-f`.

Comment: [kubectl documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply)

Comment: You also can't use `kubectl` with image files like the PNG file you've embedded in the question.  Can you edit the question to provide the actual files you're using and the actual command you're running (as text, not an image)?

Comment: I have edited the questions sorry for the trouble, i will stick to docker from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Use -f to specify A yaml file.